# Are there some methods to solve the quintic equation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quintics

I'd seen it on wikipedia that no analytical solutions for quintic equation. However, I would like to ask are there some methods to solve it if we just consider the odd power terms shown as below:

$ax^5+ cx^3+ex+f=0$

Comment: Even $x^5-x+1$ is not solveable by radicals since the galois group of this polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ is $S_5$

Comment: Just fyi, since $f = f\cdot x^0$, not all your terms are odd. If you were to actually have only odd terms, you could factor the polynomial into $X$ and a polynomial of degree four, which is _solvable_.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

You are wrong; there *are* analytic solutions for the general quintic equations. There aren't solutions by radicals, but if you want to learn about solving quintic equations by analytic methods, I suggest these books:

- *Geometry of the Quintic*, by Jerry Shurman;
- *Beyond the Quartic Equation*, by R. Bruce King.

Or, if you feel brave enough, you can read the classic *Lectures on the Icosahedron and the Solution of the Fifth Degree*, by Felix Klein.